# Beyond Studio For NXP Unresolved Inclusions

Tags: eclipse, ide

The issue is wrt. using BEYOND STUDIO IDE with JN5168-001-M06Z. BEYOND STUDIO, is built on the Eclipse IDE, I believe.
I have followed the required steps for setting up the IDE. Upon building the Application Templates provided (WIRELESS UART and others provided) I'm getting a plethora of errors. These are mostly unresolved inclusions.
The errors have a few times disappeared on their own, though I cannot figure how to reproduce such a scenario. Eg. One time the errors disappeared when I built the code again after the system resumed from Hibernate.
I have included a screenshot of a freshly loaded application template. Please let me know if any further information is required.
I'm running windows8.1 Professional
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to use their example?

Answer (score 2):

This is usefull to me:

Check box "**Index source and header files opened in editor**"

On path:

**Window -> C/C++ -> Indexer.**

Good luck.